# stuck with structures, gets and puts

Tags: c, structure, header-files

I stuck with this code.
I saved this header file (header.h) at the same folder where I saved the main.c

```
struct user{
     int userID;
     char firstName[30];
     char surName[30];
};
```

this is my main.c file which `header.h` belongs to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <header.h>

int main()
{
    struct user Richard;
    struct user Kelvin;
    struct user Ann;

    Richard.userID = 1;
    Kelvin.userID = 2;
    Ann.userID = 3;

    puts("Enter the first name of user 1");
    gets(Richard.firstname);
    puts("Enter the Surname of user 1");
    gets(Richard.surname);

    puts("\n\nEnter the first name of user 2");
    gets(Kelvin.firstname);
    puts("Enter the Surname of user 2");
    gets(Kelvin.surname);

    puts("\n\nEnter the first name of user 3");
    gets(Ann.firstname);
    puts("Enter the Surname of user 3");
    gets(Ann.surname);

    printf("\n\n user 1 ID is %d \n", Richard.userID);
    printf("user 1 full name is %s %s. \n\n", Richard.firstname,Richard.surname);
    printf("user 2 ID is %d \n", Kelvin.userID);
    printf("user 2 full name is %s %s. \n\n",  Kelvin.firstname,Kelvin.surname);
    printf("user 3 ID is %d \n", Ann.userID);
    printf("user 3 full name is %s %s. \n", Ann.firstname,Ann.surname);
    return 0;
}
```

I use CodeBlocks. This code doesn't run. When I run this code the build log says
 `fatal error: header.h: No such file or directory
     #include <header.h>`
 I can't find the bug on this code.

Comment: #include "header.h"

Comment: Try `#include "header.h"`

Comment: When i correct the mistake it says  error: 'struct user' has no member named 'firstName'

Comment: You wrote `firstName` in the struct definition and `firstname` in your code.

Comment: The functions `gets` has been removed from the C language. I would recommend to get a new source for learning C, your book/teacher is 20+ years behind everyone else. There is no reason to learn how people used to write C programs in the 1980s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main.c code,
Replace `#include <header.h>` with `#include "header.h"`

In your `header.c` code,
Replace surName with surname
Replace firstName with firstname

Comment: Don't change the variables' names! In header.h you used surName, firstName. But in main.c you used surname, firstname instead of surName, firstName

Comment: You can edit your answer and add this information there, instead of posting as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

dont use `#include<header.h>`

use `#include "header.h"`

Answer (score 1):

As several people noted, you should use this syntax:

```
#include "header.h"
```

If you use angle brackets in your `#include` syntax, the compiler looks for your file in the system directories.

If you use quotes, the compiler looks for the file first in the same directory where the c-file is, and only if not found, it looks in the system directory.

You should always use quotes for files you write yourself. Leave angle brackets for Standard library (and *possibly* other libraries).